# Converting a column in pandas with timestamps into local time knowing the timezone

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Suppose we have a pandas dataframe that have tow columns, one contains timestamps which are in GMT timezone but that is not known by the data and another column that contains timezones as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2016-02-16 13:59:12, 2015-07-22 15:07:06], 'Time_zone': ['Asia/Bangkok', 'America/Mexico_City']})
```

i want to convert the timestamps in the first column into local time using the timestamp in the second column and store that into a new column named 'local_time'

I tried the following

```
import datetime
import pytz

df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('GMT'))  

df['local_time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.astimezone(pytz.timezone(df['Time_zone'].apply(lambda x: x))))
```

but it is giving the follwing error

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried converting the df elements to `datetime` objects?

Comment: Yes, the data in the 'Time' column is in the 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp' format. I know that it is in GMT but it doesn't know that about itself

Comment: can you please right down the whole answer with all the apply functions and so on, if you advice on using apply()

Comment: I don't have a whole answer, hence the comments.

Comment: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp' got this error

Comment: That was the class with method, you must include the module: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(aTimeStamp, tz=aTimeZone)`